# Device /dev/sdb1 not found (or ignored by filtering)

Tags: centos, lvm, pv

I am trying to add a physical volume for use to add volume groups and thus LV inside them. Sadly I am getting the following error.

```
[root@server ~]# pvcreate /dev/sdb1
Device /dev/sdb1 not found (or ignored by filtering).

[root@server ~]# fdisk -l /dev/sdb

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdb'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sdb: 19966.2 GB, 19966213488640 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 2427420 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1      267350  2147483647+  ee  GPT
```

I would appreciate any help you could give. This would be my first time having to add a pv and when researching the issue I didn't come across anything that was of much help.

OS is centos 6 - 64bit

Filters

```
# By default we accept every block device:
filter = [ "a/.*/" ]

# Exclude the cdrom drive
# filter = [ "r|/dev/cdrom|" ]

# When testing I like to work with just loopback devices:
# filter = [ "a/loop/", "r/.*/" ]

# Or maybe all loops and ide drives except hdc:
# filter =[ "a|loop|", "r|/dev/hdc|", "a|/dev/ide|", "r|.*|" ]

# Use anchors if you want to be really specific
# filter = [ "a|^/dev/hda8$|", "r/.*/" ]
```

Parted:

```
parted /dev/sdb "unit s" "print"
Model: Adaptec AdaptecRAID5 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 38996510720s
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
```

Comment: OK, so what filters do you have in `/etc/lvm.conf`? And while you're at it, show us your partition table.

Comment: Show these with `grep filter /etc/lvm.conf` and `parted /dev/sdb "unit s" "print"`

Comment: Filters: http://pastie.org/8201254

Comment: Parted: http://pastie.org/8201275

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The partition type in the [MBR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) is set to "`ee`" meaning that there should be a [GPT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) partition table on the disk, but as `parted` shows, there isn't a GPT table at all.

You need to either:
a) use parted to make a GPT partition, and use that partition as the PV
b) remove the partition table from the MBR altogether and just use block device `/dev/sdb` as the PV

Comment: I used parted to make a GPT partition. I then went to format it : mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb1
mke2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
mkfs.ext4: Size of device /dev/sdb1 too big to be expressed in 32 bits
 using a blocksize of 4096.

Comment: @awmusic12635 you won't format this partition, you'll use pvcreate to turn it into a physical volume, lvcreate to create logical volume(s) from it and *then* you'll format the logical volumes with a filesystem.

Comment: You're using EL6. The maximum possible ext4 filesystem size is restricted to 16Tb because EL6 mkfs does not know about the `64bit` filesystem flag. If you had EL7, you could make a 19Tb ext4 filesystem. Either use another filesystem like XFS, or do what @DerfK said and make smaller LVM Logical Volumes.

Answer (score 4):

I found that I either needed to reboot the server or run 'partprobe /dev/sdaX' in order for pvcreate to be properly informed of the partition.

Also, fdisk is not lvm aware so it was handing out errors about partitions making me think there was a bigger problem when that was simply not the case.

Answer (score 4):

The block device type could also be a problem. If you run `pvcreate` with `-vvvv` and you see an error like "Skipping: Unrecognised LVM device type 251", then you have to add the magic number to the allowed devices list.

Just look up the device type for the number in `/proc/devices` and add it to the `devices` section of the lvm config `/etc/lvm/lvm.conf`, for example:

`types = [ "bcache", 251 ]`

That's it, you can now use `pvcreate` as expected.

Comment: The `-vvvv` helped me to find out that in the script, where `pvcreate` was immediately following `parted /dev/nvme0n1 set 1 lvm on` there is a short, but notable moment while device `/dev/nvme0n1p1` is recreated by `udev`. So, `pvcreate` **really** couldn't find it, filing with the given error, while issuing the same command in a shell finished successfully.

Comment: @TimurBakeyev okay, *THAT* is a good catch ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Please run the below command before pvcreate

```
partprobe
partprobe /dev/sdb
```

Then run your command

```
pvcreate /dev/sdb1
```

Note : Sometimes you need to update your kernel manually. Thats why the above command required.

Answer (score 2):

Your parted output shows that you don't have any partitions, thus `/dev/sdb1` doesn't exist. You need to create the partition first.

Comment: Odd, It seems fdisk and parted gave different outputs. Thanks